# Ruby on Rails - add class to body only if content_for?(:partial) is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a `:sticky_footer` region in my application.html.haml file:

```
= yield :sticky_footer
```

I'd like to add a `has-sticky-footer` class to the body node if the sticky_footer region has content inside.

I tried doing:

```
body{class: content_for?(:sticky_footer) ? "has-sticky-footer" : "no-sticky-footer"}
```

However this seems to evaluate to false even if the content_for is defined later in code.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

> However this seems to evaluate to false even if the content_for is
>   defined later in code.

That's right.  At the time of the test `content_for?` it hasn't been defined, so the value is false.

Do the definition first... before the body line

```
-content_for :sticky_footer do
  # define the content here
```

Then insert the class for the body

later in the code you can yield the content_for

```
=content_for :sticky_footer
# or
=yield :sticky_footer
```

Comment: thanks, however I'd like to place the :content_for(:sticky_footer) inside of the views where it is used, and their content is placed above the body tag, any other ideas?

Comment: Just to be clear, where it's used and where it's defined don't have to be the same place.  You can define above the body tag, you can use wherever you want (as long as it's before where defined).  And it has to be defined before you test `content_for?`